# How to change the /tf topic message published in the data？

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the MIT dataset to evaluate the gmapping algorithm, but the coordinate transformation maintained in the/tf topic published in the dataset is as follows:

[image: image description]

I need to use the original odom coordinate system to build /tf instead of odom_ combined. Known as topic/base_ odometry/odom releases the coordinate transformation of odom. Could you please release a new/tf topic, as shown in the figure below:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409013/how-to-change-the-/tf-topic-message-published-in-the-data%EF%BC%9F/) by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One method is to write a script to generate a new bag file using the rosbag API. See these links:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2